# Finding a projection of$e^x$ onto subspace of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Find in $C[0,1]$ with inner product $<f,g>=\int^1_0 f(x)g(x)dx$, fnd the projection of $e^x$ onto subspace of polynomials of degree 1 or less.

I want to find an othonormal basis for the subspace of degree$\le1$.  So I tried to normalize thevector 1, so

$<1,1>=\int_0^11dx=1$, so $e_1=1$

Now we have to do $<e,x>=<1,x>=\int_0^1xdx=\frac{1}{2}$

So $u_2=x-<e_1,x>e_1=x-\frac{1}{2}$

So now I do $<1,x-\frac{1}{2}>=0$, so I feel like I've done something wrong, as I don't thnk that my second coordinate for the basis vector is (0,1).

Any help?  Thanks

Comment: You are actually well on your way to Gram-Schmidt orthogonalizing the basis $\{1,x\}$. As usual $u_1=e_1$, $u_2=e_2-\langle e_2,e_1\rangle e_1$. Next you should find the squared norms of $u_1$ and $u_2$, and then do the projection.

Comment: In your definition its $<e_2,e_2>$ and not $<e_1,e_2>$? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Fixed now. Sorry about that.

Comment: no problem!  Would the squared norms for $u_1=1$ and for $u_2=(x^-1/2)^2$?  And the projection is $\frac{<e_1,u_2>}{<e_1,e_1>}e_1$?  But I would still get 0 @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: The squared norms are surely
$$||1||^2=\langle 1,1\rangle=\int_0^11\,dx,$$ and
$$||u_2||^2=\int_0^1(x-\frac12)^2\,dx.$$ Then the projection of $e_3=e^x$ onto the span of $u_1$ and $u_2$ is
$$
p(e_3)=\frac{\langle u_1,e_3\rangle}{\langle u_1,u_1\rangle} u_1+
\frac{\langle u_2,e_3\rangle}{\langle u_2,u_2\rangle} u_2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Finding the orthogonal projection can also be done by solving for a,b, the system $$\langle 1,e^x-(a+bx)\rangle=0\\
\langle x,e^x-(a+bx)\rangle=0$$
or, in the matrix form,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\langle1,1\rangle & \langle 1,x\rangle \\
\langle x,1\rangle & \langle x,x\rangle\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}\langle 1,e^x\rangle\\\langle x,e^x\rangle\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different approach. We need to minimize the equation

> $$ f(a,b) = ||e^x-(a+bx)||_2^2= \int_{0}^{1} (e^x-a-bx)^2 dx. $$

This can be done by solving the system

> $$ f_a(a,b)=0,\quad f_b(a,b)=0 $$