# Distance between function and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Let $f(x)=cos^{n+1}(x)$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In the real vector space $C([-\pi,\pi],\mathbb{R})$, we consider the inner product $\int_{\pi}^{\pi} \! f(x) g(x) dx$. My question is:

> What is the distance $d$ between $f$ and $V=span\{ 1,cos(x),sin(x),...,cos(nx),sin(nx)\}$?

I do not know how to attack this problem in a simple way. If I'm not mistaken, $d$ is going to be the distance between $f$ and the orthogonal projection, $\overline{f}$ of $f$ over $V$, but I could not evaluate the integrals required to calculate $\overline{f}$. Any help?

Edit(1): I'm mainly interested in a solution using only concepts from basic linear algebra (inner products, orthogonalization, etc.) and not Fourier series or derivatives.

Edit(2): Computer calculations seem to suggest that $d=\pi/2^n$.

Comment: Do you know how to compute Fourier series?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172158/finding-a-projection-ofex-onto-subspace-of-polynomials/1173076#1173076).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my class we do not learn about Fourier series yet.

Comment: I already referred you to a technique that you can use in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$ g(x) = a_0+\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \sin kx +\sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k \cos kx  $$

where $a_0,a_i,b_i$ needs to be determined by minimizing the following function

$$ f(a_0,a_k,b_k) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left[ \cos^{n+1}(x)- \left( a_0+\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \sin kx +\sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k \cos kx \right) \right]dx $$

which can be done by solving the system of equations

$$ f_{a_0}=0 \\ f_{a_k} =0\quad k=1,\dots,n \\ f_{b_k} =0 \quad  k=1,\dots,n  $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This method is elegant and seems to solve the problem, but I was looking for a solution without derivatives, as this exercise is for a course in Linear Algebra and we do not use this kind of methods here.

Comment: As I said $a_0,a_k,b_k$ are Fourier coefficient of Fourier series. Work out the projection technique and you will see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, I know, it's just that I would like to avoid using Fourier coefficients and/or derivatives. Anyway, thank you for your patience and, if I do not receive any more responses, I will gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sines and cosines form an [orthonormal basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html) for the space of square-integrable functions with the inner product
$$
\tfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)g(x)\,dx.
$$ $V_n=span\{ 1,\cos(x),\sin(x),...,\cos(nx),\sin(nx)\}$ is a linear space of trigonometric polynomials of nth degree. Using [trigonometric power formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula) we see that $\cos^{n+1}\theta\in V_{n+1}\supset V_n$ with the orthogonal component being $\frac{1}{2^n}\cos((n+1)\theta)$. Its length calculated in the inner product above is $\dfrac{1}{2^n}.$ We can call it the distance between $\cos^{n+1}\theta$ and $V_n.$