# Why finding the projection of $e^x$ onto subspace of polynomials is given by this system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Why the [projection of $e^x$ onto subspace of polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172158/finding-a-projection-ofex-onto-subspace-of-polynomials) is given by [this system](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1173069/166180):

> Finding the orthogonal projection can also be done by solving for a,b,
>   the system $$\langle 1,e^x-(a+bx)\rangle=0\\ \langle
>  x,e^x-(a+bx)\rangle=0$$ or, in the matrix form, $$ \begin{pmatrix}
>  \langle1,1\rangle & \langle 1,x\rangle \\ \langle x,1\rangle & \langle
> x,x\rangle\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}
>  =\begin{pmatrix}\langle 1,e^x\rangle\\\langle x,e^x\rangle\end{pmatrix}.$$

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orthogonal projection of a function $f$ onto a subspace $U$ is the unique function $g$ such that
$$f=g+h,$$
with $g\in U$ and $h\in U^{\perp}$, i.e. $\langle h,u\rangle=0$ for all $u\in U$. Note that $h=f-g$.

In this case $f=e^x$ and $U=\operatorname{span}\{1,x\}$ so $g\in U$ means that $g=a+bx$ for some scalars $a$ and $b$, and hence
$$h=f-g=e^x-(a+bx),$$
and we want $\langle h,u\rangle=0$ for all $u\in U$. Because $U=\operatorname{span}\{1,x\}$ it suffices to check that
$$\langle h,1\rangle=0\qquad\text{ and }\qquad \langle h,x\rangle=0,$$
which yield precisely the given equations. Bilinearity of the inner product allows you to write this system of equations in the given matrix form.